# how to set mile radius from a CLLocation?

Tags: swift, google-places-api, cllocation, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm using Google Places Autocomplete API and want to set a bounds for the API call using Google's example:

```
 // Set bounds to inner-west Sydney Australia.
let neBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.843366,
                                            longitude: 151.134002)
let swBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.875725,
                                            longitude: 151.200349)
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: neBoundsCorner,
                                 coordinate: swBoundsCorner)
```

However I want to set my bounds from the user's current location, which I have stored as a CLLocation. How can I turn that one point into 2 points x miles NE and SW from the center?